# PANDAS Function manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, group-by

So I have a dataset that looks like:

[image]

I want to aggregate for each ORIGIN_CITY_NAME, count the number of unique Carrier in that City. Example:

For Dallas/Fort Worth,TX: Let's say they have 4 different UNIQUE_CARRIER like AA(American Airlines), Delta Airlines, Southwest Airlines, and JetBlue.

Then the output should look like:

```
    Out[1]:
    ORIGIN_CITY_NAME        # of unique carriers 
0   Dallas/Fort Worth,TX            4
1   San Francisco, CA               5 
...
```

Any ideas? I tried:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need something like `nunique`?

```
df.groupby('ORIGIN_CITY_NAME')['UNIQUE_CARRIER'].nunique()
```